# Display TreeView using Template in GoJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, gojs

This is the first I am working on GoJs. I am pretty sure that this is very much possible. This is what I want in my webpage. I am able to reproduce it.

http://gojs.net/latest/samples/records.html

I want below treeview in both the panels in the above link.

http://gojs.net/latest/samples/treeView.html

How can I implement it ?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried using Groups to display a treeView of nodes in each?

Comment: @SimonSarris I am trying to create treeview in FieldTemplate. It didnot work. I haven't tried using groups. Can you suggest me on how to use Groups ?